# jekyll works weird

Tags: jekyll

In my local website, there is error that I can't open file.
[llike this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5QHU.png)
How can I solve this problem???

Comment: What is the structure of the unprocessed files?

Comment: I use the theme [so-simple-theme](https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme)  so it's the same structure.

Comment: where are the post files located in the jekyll directory and how are the named?

Comment: hah... I just `jekyll build` again. The file name is now FINE, however `jekyll serve` result is same with above texts I wrote.

Comment: [This repository](https://github.com/plzfday/plzfday.github.io) works perfectly well locally. It can be interesting to see what changes you've made since then.

Comment: I clone my repo and command `bundle install` > `jekyll serve`.  But doesn't work. Could you tell me how did you do?